# Do you capitalize commonly-lowercased titles at the beginning of a sentence?

Tags: grammaticality, capitalization

Sometimes titles are made lowercase to achieve some desired effect.  The musical artist *gnash*, his song "i hate u, i love you", as well as any of the people on [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_people_with_lower_case_names_and_pseudonyms) are some examples.  When starting a sentence with a name like these, should the first letter be capitalized?  For example, which of the following is correct?

> gnash reached the top of the charts this week.
>
> Gnash reached the top of the charts this week.

Comment: If your preferred style guide doesn't address this, or if you're conflicted, you can always write around it: *The artist gnash reached* or *'gnash' reached* or any such.

Comment: Related: *[Can a sentence start with a small letter?](/questions/68660)* and *[How do you capitalize a proper noun such as “iPhone”?](/questions/9063)*. Also see *[How to cite an author who does not capltalize her name if you are beginning a sentence with her name](/questions/151863/)*

Comment: Elsewhere on the web you will find extended discussions about e.e. cummings, k.d. lang, danah boyd, and will.i.am.

Answer (score -2):

The second one is correct.

> Gnash reached the top of the charts this week.

The first letter in a sentence is conventionally capitalized. But if there is no specification for this, and you're sure that *gnash* is in the accurate case, it's best to write something before it, like mentioned in the comments.

> Singer-songwriter gnash reached the top of the charts this week.

Comment: How would you write a sentence that starts with iPhone?

Comment: It would be better to say that capitalizing the first word of a sentence is conventional, but certain styles (e.g. Garner's) allow for stylistic variation; **always** is clearly not accurate as you immediately identify an exception.

Comment: *No matter what, the first letter in a sentence is always capitalized. **Always.*** What about the sentence "2016 was an eventful year"? The first letter in that sentence is "w", and it isn't capitalized.

Comment: @sumelic except technically the first  letter in that sentence is "T" for "Twenty" (or "Two thousand").

Comment: In any case,  Aravind is exactly wrong here.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft: "2016" does not technically start with "T". It is pronounced with the sound /t/, but a sound is not a letter. The rule about spelling out numbers does not apply to years, as far as I know, so it wouldn't even make sense to replace "2016" with something like "Twenty thousand sixteen" or "Two thousand sixteen" in writing.

Comment: On English Language Learners, English sentences always start with capital letters, or numbers.
Anyone, including *gnash*, is entitled to spell his name however he likes - including Tom Lehrer’s Henry spelled *Hen3ry but the 3 was silent*. That doesn’t mean he can dictate how you spell it.
He who tried to insist on *The Artist Formerly Known as Prince* got how far, please? If you knew his music, did you go for *The Artist…* or… uh… *Prince*?
*iPhone* is pretentious marketing; a sentence which had to start that way, not *The iPhone* would be the exception, not the rule.

Comment: Oops… I forgot to mention these are not *commonly-lowercased* anything, nor even *titles*

Comment: Arguably these names should be written as Iphone and Gnash regardless of where in the sentence they appear. The other variations are rather just imitating stylized text from logotypes in plain text, not following language rules.

Comment: @HåkanLindqvist No, the word "iPhone" has to be spelt like that, since it's a brand name. That is the way it's spelled, atleast most of the time: http://economictimes.indiatimes.com/magazines/panache/samsung-vs-apple-now-iphone-8-battery-swelling-reported-in-us/articleshow/61070742.cms http://www.hindustantimes.com/tech/google-s-pixel-2-2xl-launch-apple-s-iphone-and-samsung-s-galaxy-could-feel-the-heat/story-j7vFVMqNSuvfFkyM9Du1IN.html http://indiatoday.intoday.in/technology/story/iphone-9-iphone-9-plus-to-ditch-touch-id-in-favor-of-face-id-next-year-report/1/1067884.html